# Linux collect CPU time per shared library file

Tags: linux, libraries, cpu-usage, statistics

Is there a way to -in the background- collect cumulative cpu time stats per shared library? Without modifying applications or libraries? Ideally a solution that'll (also) work on arm (Jetson / Pi).

There's `/proc/{process_id}/stat` to do something at a process level, but is it also possible at object / library file level?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but requires support from the kernel and debug symbols for your application and libraries:

```bsh
$ perf record --all-user --pid PID

# wait at least 1 minute, then press Ctrl-C

$ perf report > perf.log
```

Without kernel support and debug symbols I'm not sure you can get this information.